# How to download images attached to a tweet from the tweet link?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Since the Twitter API is no longer free how to download images from tweet links using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Since the tweet page is dynamically generated, using BeautifulSoup to generate html won't work. Hence I have used selenium to generate the html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
base_url = tweet_url
browser.get(base_url)
time.sleep(2)
html = browser.page_source
soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
images = soup.find_all('img')
for img in images:
    if img['alt'] == 'Image':
        print(img['src'])
```